# В Vim не отображается название текущего режима

Tags: vim

При работе в Vim (на xubuntu 16.04 LTS) в левом нижнем углу не отображается в каком режиме происходит работа. Например, при нажатии "i" vim переходит в режим вставки, но внизу не написано: "--ВСТАВКА--".

Программа vim (по крайней мере запускаю её такой командой), установил с помощью `apt-get install vim`

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr 08 2016 11:38:28)
Заплатки: 1-1689
С изменениями, внесёнными pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Скомпилирован  pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Огромная версия без графического интерфейса.  Включённые (+) и отключённые (-) особенности:
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +terminfo
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +textobjects
+channel         +gettext         -mzscheme        +timers
+cindent         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clientserver    +iconv           +packages        -toolbar
-clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +job             -perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            -ruby            -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xsmp
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_save
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xpm
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
            общесистемный файл vimrc: "$VIM/vimrc"
         пользовательский файл vimrc: "$HOME/.vimrc"
  второй пользовательский файл vimrc: "~/.vim/vimrc"
          пользовательский файл exrc: "$HOME/.exrc"
          значение $VIM по умолчанию: "/usr/share/vim"
Параметры компиляции: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Сборка: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl
```

Comment: отлично! видите, там в конце вывода `vim --version` перечислены файлы (общесистемный, пользовательский и т.д. и т.п.). какие из них существуют у вас в системе?

Comment: Только ~/.vimrc который я сам и создал

Comment: и `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` нет? (это, скорее всего, ссылка на `/etc/vim/vimrc`, который, скорее всего, входит в пакет `vim-common`).

Comment: Нет, этот файл есть (/usr/share/vim/vimrc или /etc/vim/vimrc)

Comment: смотрите дальше: `grep -v '^\("\|$\)' /etc/vim/vimrc` и `grep -v '^\("\|$\)' ~/.vimrc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ от [@Yaroslav](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/537436/217579) правильный:

```
:set showmode
```

Если он не помог, значит режим вставки отображается, но его не видно, так как цвет строки состояния или белым-по-белому, или черным-по-черному. Попробуйте временно установить цветовую схему по-умолчанию:

```
:colorscheme default
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, помогло. У меня, оказывается, цвет полужирного текста совпадал с цветом фона.

Answer (score 4):

Для отображения режима вставки установите

```
set showmode
```

чтобы не отображать режим вставки установите

```
set noshowmode
```

Comment: Не помогло. Я вставил set showmode в свой ~/.vimrc

Comment: Попробуйте дать команду не посредственно в vim `:set showmode`

Comment: тоже не помогло